# Converting a list of geographic coordinates to addresses

Tags: leaflet, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

I am working on a routing program that sends to the client a big list of geographic coordinates based on which i draw the route on a map (leaflet). I was wondering if there is a way to get the street names of where all those coordinates are placed, in one fast move.

I know Google's API might be a solution but i am trying to avoid it since there are some limitations with the number of requests. Also i have been using MapQuest's API for clicking on a map and retrieving the address of the place clicked, however that one has a a delay up to 1-2 seconds, for only one gps coordinate. And for a big list of them, the delay can go up to minutes, which does not help me at all.

Do you happen to know other solutions? I need results in less than 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

you should use GeoCoding There are classes written in the google api ,in you javascript code you can convert latitude longitude into addresses by geo coding and reverse geo coding

Answer (score 0):

Check Nominatim reverse geocoding http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/open-sdk/javascript/v7.0/nominatim. But generally keep in mind that if you want good performance with a lot of requests you will have to pay for that.